# File download using Websocket is slow compared to Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I wrote a simple file download program using tomcat 7.0.47 WebSocket API.
Below is the method which sends the file as binary message to the client.

```
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String path) {
        ReadableByteChannel channel = null;
        int capacity = 1024 * 100;
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(capacity);
        try {
            channel = Channels.newChannel(new FileInputStream(path));
            while(channel.read(buffer) != -1){
                buffer.flip();
                session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(buffer);
                buffer.clear();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while reading the file to download", e);
        } finally {
            if (channel != null) {
                try {
                    channel.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("Error while closing the stream", e);
                }
            }
        }    
        session.getAsyncRemote().sendText("done");
    }
```

I have timed the total download time for 5GB files using SCP, Servlet based implementation and Websocket implementation. File download using WebSocket is much slower. For 5GB file, SCP and servlet take ~50 seconds on my test machine, WebSocket takes ~180 seconds.

Can any one help me understand what is wrong with my implementation?

Are WebSockets not good for such usecase? Any tomcat configuration parameters to tweak to achieve better performance?

Comment: You should use `compact(),` not `clear().`

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help much. Clear should be less expensive than compact as it only sets the position to zero.

Comment: It was posted as a comment, not an answer. I know what `clear()` does. My point is that it is the wrong method to call. In the cases where it is correct to call `clear()` it is also correct to call `compact(),` and no more expensive; and in the cases where it isn't correct to call `clear()` you don't have any choice but to call `compact().`

Answer (score 0):

There is a max payload size for sending binary data in tomcat, i.e. `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.binaryBufferSize` referred from [tomcat doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html). The default value of it is `8192`. So the `capacity` must be less than or equal to this value.

So your code must be modified to something like this

`int capacity = session.getMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize();`

Now, increase the size of `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.binaryBufferSize` to some reasonably higher value, this may increase data transfer speed and thus the download speed.

You can change this value using context initialization parameter in `web.xml`.

Eg:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tomcat.websocket.binaryBufferSize</param-name>
    <param-value>16384</param-value>
</context-param>
```